# AngularJS - accessing child object in JSON data from controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm creating a laravel application and I'm trying to access a child object's properties in my view using Angular. I can get the whole data in my view (including child objects), but I'm  having trouble when trying to display it using Angular.

controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)

        $lang = $request->input('lang') ?? 'pt';
        $interestTranslations = Interest::with([
            'interesttranslations' => function($query) use ($lang) {
                $query->where('languageCode', $lang);
            }
        ])->get()->toArray();

        return ['translatedInterests' => $interestTranslations];
    }
```

}

js file:

```
app..controller("Interests", function ($scope, $rootScope, HobbiesService) {
        var lang = $rootScope.lang;
        HobbiesService.newData(lang).then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.interests = response["data"].translatedInterests;
        });
    })
```

html file (interest.interesttranslations works but interest.interesttranslations.name_or_other_property doesn't):

```
<p style="color: white;">{{interests}}</p> <!-- this shows the whole json datam including the child objects-->

<div class="no-padding owl-carousel" id="hobbies-container" ng-controller="Interests">
    <div ng-repeat="interest in interests">
        <img src="/img/about/{{ interest.imageName }}" alt="{{ interest.imageName }}" /> <!--this works-->
        <p style="color: white;">{{ interest.interesttranslations.name }}</p> <!--this doesn't work-->
    </div>
</div>
```

json displayed in my view when using {{ interests }}:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "applicant_id": 1,
    "imageName": "friends.png",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "interesttranslations": [{
      "interest_id": 1,
      "languageCode": "pt",
      "name": "explorar com amigos",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "applicant_id": 1,
    "imageName": "world.png",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "interesttranslations": [{
      "interest_id": 2,
      "languageCode": "pt",
      "name": "viajar",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "applicant_id": 1,
    "imageName": "tv-shows.png",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "interesttranslations": [{
      "interest_id": 3,
      "languageCode": "pt",
      "name": "séries televisivas",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }]
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `interesttranslations` is an array, not an object.

In the view try

```
{{ interest.interesttranslations[0].name }}
```

Or use an inner `ng-repeat` to iterate that array

```
<p ng-repeat="item in interest.interesttranslations">
    {{item.name}}
</p>
```

Comment: ..and that did the trick. I tried using an inner ng-repeat before to see if it would work but it didn't (ng-repeat: {{ translation in interest.interesttranslations}}). Guess I did something wrong. Any idea how I could get the child object without the array around it?